# Shell script to extract field from json data

Tags: bash, shell

I have been breaking my head over this simple script. Suppose I have a file called test.sh and the content is json can anyone tell what would be the shell script to extract a particular field from the json data. For example the content of the file be

```
{  
   "boo":"1",
   "handled":"0",
   "credits":"0.6",
   "execute":0,
   "available":[  
      "299258"
   ],
   "approved":[  

   ],
   "blizzard":"143030",
   "reviewable":[  
      "930932",
      "283982",
      "782821"
   ],
   "units":"6",
   "pending":[  
      "298233",
      "329449"
   ],
   "hobbit":"blasphemy"
}
```

and I want to extract the value of "execute" alone.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Use a proper `JSON` parser like `jq`

Comment: Download and install `jq` from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ and just do `jq '.execute' < json-file`

Comment: Is there no way other than jq. I don't want to use jq and that's the problem.